# Dropzone.js doesn't work in wordpress frontend posting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, dropzone.js

I'm building a front-end posting form on my WP site. The simplified code of my form is as follows:

```html
<form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="/add-property-query/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- post name -->
        <fieldset name="name">
         <label for="title">Name:</label>
         <input type="text" id="title" value="TestName" tabindex="5" name="title" />
        </fieldset>
     
        <!-- images - _thumbnail_id -->
        <div class="images">
       <label for="boss_thumbnail">Front of the Bottle</label>
          <input type="file" name="boss_thumbnail" id="boss_thumbnail" tabindex="25" />
        </div>
    
     
        <fieldset class="submit">
         <button type="submit" value="Post Review" tabindex="40" id="submit" name="submit">Submit data and files!</button>
        </fieldset>
     
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_post" />
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>
       </form>
```

I use an image uploading input which works perfectly. That is the part of the server side code, which processes the image upload:

```html
//INSERT OUR MEDIA ATTACHMENTS
         if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){
             require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
             require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
             require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
         }
          if ($_FILES) {
             foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                 if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
                     return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];
                 }
             }
             $boss_thumbnail = media_handle_upload('boss_thumbnail', $pid); // set cover
         }
         if ($boss_thumbnail > 0){
             //set the image as thumbnail:
             update_post_meta($pid,'_thumbnail_id',$boss_thumbnail);
         }// END SAVING FILE
```

I need exactly the same uploading mechanism with my other form fields working using dropzone.js. As they require on their site (dropzonejs.com), I included `<script src="./path/to/dropzone.js"></script>` and added `dropzone` class to the form. My HTML now is the following:

```html
<script src="./path/to/dropzone.js"></script>
<form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="/add-property-query/" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- post name -->
        <fieldset name="name">
         <label for="title">Name:</label>
         <input type="text" id="title" value="TestName" tabindex="5" name="title" />
        </fieldset>
     
        <!-- images - _thumbnail_id -->
        <div class="images">
       <label for="boss_thumbnail">Front of the Bottle</label>
          <input type="file" name="boss_thumbnail" id="boss_thumbnail" tabindex="25" />
        </div>
    
     
        <fieldset class="submit">
         <button type="submit" value="Post Review" tabindex="40" id="submit" name="submit">Submit data and files!</button>
        </fieldset>
     
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_post" />
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>
       </form>
```

Dropzone found the form element with the class dropzone, automatically attached itself to it. On the front-end everything works fine. On the site they say that the uploaded files can be handled just as if there would have been a html input like this:

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

So, on the server I change `$boss_thumbnail = media_handle_upload('boss_thumbnail', $pid);` to the `$boss_thumbnail = media_handle_upload('file', $pid);` but then WP returns the following error: `Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in formatting.php on line 1025`.

I even used this article (https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Combine-normal-form-with-Dropzone) to "Combine normal form with Dropzone" but it didn't help me. The final HTML code is as follows:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://eventboss.org/wp-content/themes/Travelo/css/dropzone.css">
 <script src="http://eventboss.org/wp-content/themes/Travelo/js/dropzone.js"></script>
 <script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    Dropzone.options.new_post = { // The camelized version of the ID of the form element
   
     // The configuration we've talked about above
     autoProcessQueue: false,
     uploadMultiple: false,
     parallelUploads: 100,
     maxFiles: 100,
   
     // The setting up of the dropzone
     init: function() {
       var myDropzone = this;
   
       // First change the button to actually tell Dropzone to process the queue.
       this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
         // Make sure that the form isn't actually being sent.
         e.preventDefault();
         e.stopPropagation();
         myDropzone.processQueue();
       });
   
       // Listen to the sendingmultiple event. In this case, it's the sendingmultiple event instead
       // of the sending event because uploadMultiple is set to true.
       this.on("sendingmultiple", function() {
         // Gets triggered when the form is actually being sent.
         // Hide the success button or the complete form.
       });
       this.on("successmultiple", function(files, response) {
         // Gets triggered when the files have successfully been sent.
         // Redirect user or notify of success.
       });
       this.on("errormultiple", function(files, response) {
         // Gets triggered when there was an error sending the files.
         // Maybe show form again, and notify user of error
       });
     }
   
   }
  })
 </script>

<form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="/add-property-query/" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <!-- post name -->
       <fieldset name="name">
        <label for="title">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="title" value="TestName" tabindex="5" name="title" />
       </fieldset>
   
    
       <fieldset class="submit">
        <button type="submit" value="Post Review" tabindex="40" id="submit" name="submit">Submit data and files!</button>
       </fieldset>
    
       <input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_post" />
       <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>
      </form>
```

On the server-side I made only one change mentioned above. How can I make my script process image upload correctly with dropzone.js script used?

Comment: What is this code: formatting.php on line 1025

Comment: I think this line `<input type="file" name="boss_thumbnail" id="boss_thumbnail" tabindex="25" />` needs to be `<input type="file" name="file" id="boss_thumbnail" tabindex="25" />`

Comment: What @jonmrich said.

Comment: @jonmrich @Will I don't think so. In fact I even removed the field `<input type="file" name="boss_thumbnail" id="boss_thumbnail" tabindex="25" />` from the HTML because according to the instruction on their site, when dropzone attaches itself to the form it behaves in the way as if there were `<input type="file" name="file" id="boss_thumbnail" tabindex="25" />` field.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<input type="file" name="boss_thumbnail" id="boss_thumbnail" tabindex="25" />
```

to

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="boss_thumbnail" tabindex="25" />
```

Comment: I don't think so. In fact I even removed the field `<input type="file" name="boss_thumbnail" id="boss_thumbnail" tabindex="25" />` from the HTML because according to the instruction on their site, when dropzone attaches itself to the form it behaves in the way as if there were `<input type="file" name="file" id="boss_thumbnail" tabindex="25" />` field.